# Fix javacode to display error message for fileupload

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have a form for user to upload image and i would like to validate that image before uploading. So i found this script on the internet, it's validation is working ok but it does not display error message. Because I don't know how to declare element for error message to be displayed. I just learn javascript, it usually uses `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript";`. But this code is so advanced, I could not figure how to fix it.

Here is file input inside my form. I have added `<span class='error-message'></span>` in line 11. I would like error messages to be displayed in this span element.

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
echo "<div style='padding-left:0' class=\"fileinput fileinput-new col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4\" data-provides=\"fileinput\">
        <div class=\"fileinput-new thumbnail\" style=\"width: 266px; height: 220px;\">
            <img src=\"../images/default_image.png\" alt=\"chọn ảnh\">
        </div>
    <div class=\"fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail\" style=\"width: 277px; height: 220px\"></div>
        <div>
            <span class=\"btn btn-default btn-file\"><span class=\"fileinput-new\">Select image</span><span class=\"fileinput-exists\">Change</span><input type=\"file\" onchange=\"getImg(this,500,'jpeg|png')\" id=\"file$i\" name=\"file[]\"></span>
            <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-default fileinput-exists\" data-dismiss=\"fileinput\">Remove</a>
            <span class='error-message'></span>
        </div>
    </div>";
}
?>
```

Here is the java Script code:

```
<script>
function getImg(input,max,accepted){
var upImg=new Image(),test,size,msg=input.form;
msg=msg.elements[0].children[0];
return input.files?validate():
(upImg.src=input.value,upImg.onerror=upImg.onload=validate);
    "author: b.b. Troy III p.a.e";
function validate(){
    test=(input.files?input.files[0]:upImg);
    size=(test.size||test.fileSize)/1024;
    mime=(test.type||test.mimeType);

mime.match(RegExp(accepted,'i'))?
size>max?(input.form.reset(),msg.innerHTML=max+"KB Exceeded!"):
msg.innerHTML="Upload ready...":    
(input.form.reset(),msg.innerHTML=accepted+" file type(s) only!")
}
}
</script>
```

This is the working demo of this script from the author: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CVYFN/73/). How can I applied this in my case?

Comment: Java is not JavaScript so do not refer to JavaScript as Java.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way would be:

In you html replace:

```
<span class='error-message'></span>
```

with:

```
<span id='error-message'></span>
```

And in you JS replace:

```
msg=msg.elements[0].children[0];
```

with:

```
var msg=document.getElementById('error-message');
```